# Make ElasticSearch handle fields that contain ranges

Tags: elasticsearch

In the data that i'm indexing into Elasticsearch, i have fields that are representing ranges of years, like `1948-` and `1999-2002`

Is there a way to make Elastic interpret these values to make any of the years contained in the range searchable?

**Example:**
A document has a field named yearRange that contains the value `1999-2001`
If i search for `q=yearRange:2000`, I want the document to match.

I can see that you can solve it by letting a script generate an array of years, but i wonder if there is some other way.

Elastic 2.4 is the version in use.

Comment: I think this is better handled at indexing time. Meaning, do the right thing and index those years in two separate fields. Then it would be much much easier and performant to run range queries.

Comment: Also if there's an opportunity to upgrade to ES 5, range types are [supported natively](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/range.html)

Comment: If you store "start" and "end" years separately then you can create a filter for that. Handling missing start and end values makes it a bit trickier though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the years are continuous then you should store start year and end year and you can easily do range queries on that. If dates are not continuous then you can represent every interval as nested documents and query over that in the same fashion.
 Generating every year and putting it in an array will create an extra load as now every year will be indexed, doc_values will be created for them, your _source will be heavy etc etc. If you can execute queries with less data then you should go for that.